# Kubernetes Dashboard CrashLoopBackOff, Get error "connect: no route to host", How could I fix it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have deployed the Kubernetes dashboard which ended up in   `CrashLoopBackOff` status. When I run:

```
$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-767dc7d4d-mc2sm --namespace=kube-system
```

the output is:

```
Error from server: Get https://10.4.211.53:10250/containerLogs/kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard-767dc7d4d-mc2sm/kubernetes-dashboard: dial tcp 10.4.211.53:10250: connect: no route to host
```

How can I fix this? Does this means that the port 10250 isn't open?

---

Update：

@LucaBrasi
`Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-767dc7d4d-mc2sm" not found`

`systemctl status kubelet --full` Output is ：

```
kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since 一 2018-09-10 15:04:57 CST; 1 day 23h ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 93440 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 78.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─93440 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --network-plugin=cni
```

Output for `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

`NAMESPACE     NAME                                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-qh6zb                                    1/1       Running            2          3d
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-xbzgn                                    1/1       Running            1          3d
kube-system   etcd-twsr-whtestserver01.garenanet.com                      1/1       Running            2          3d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-twsr-whtestserver01.garenanet.com            1/1       Running            2          3d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-twsr-whtestserver01.garenanet.com   1/1       Running            2          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-2bnmx                                 1/1       Running            3          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-r58j6                                 1/1       Running            0          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-wq6ls                                 1/1       Running            0          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-ds7lg                                            1/1       Running            0          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-fx46d                                            1/1       Running            0          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-ph7qq                                            1/1       Running            2          3d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-twsr-whtestserver01.garenanet.com            1/1       Running            1          3d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-767dc7d4d-mc2sm                        0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   877        3d`

Comment: Port 10250 is typically the kubelet agent port. Can you show the output of:  kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-767dc7d4d-mc2sm and systemctl status kubelet --full

Comment: It means that something is not right with your networking/CNI configs.   What overlay did you install?

Comment: @Rico My network provider is flannel

Comment: @Rukeith how did you deploy the cluster (what tool) and did you deploy kubernetes dashboard from the [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard)? Also the flannel was deployed manually or you used automatic deployment, for example (CoreOS's Tectonic)?

Comment: @aurelius I install flannel with this tutorial 
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-centos-7/

I deploy dashboard with these yml file. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

Comment: Can you run kubectl get pods - -all-namespaces see if all pods are running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when I reproduced all the steps from the tutorial you've linked - my dashboard was in `CrashLoopBackOff`state. After I performed this steps and applied new dashboard yaml from the official github documentation (there seems to be no difference from the one you've posted), the dashboard was working properly.

First, list all the objects related to Kubernetes dashboard:

```
kubectl get secret,sa,role,rolebinding,services,deployments --namespace=kube-system | grep dashboard
```

Delete them:

```
kubectl delete deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system 
kubectl delete service kubernetes-dashboard  --namespace=kube-system 
kubectl delete role kubernetes-dashboard-minimal --namespace=kube-system 
kubectl delete rolebinding kubernetes-dashboard-minimal --namespace=kube-system
kubectl delete sa kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system 
kubectl delete secret kubernetes-dashboard-certs --namespace=kube-system
kubectl delete secret kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder --namespace=kube-system
```

Now apply Kubernetes dashboard yaml:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Please tell me if this worked for you as well, and if it did, treat it as a workaround as I don't know the reason yet - I am investigating.